# Altering the elements of a collection in a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

Can I do the following in PHP?

```
foreach ($collection as &$element)
    $element = ...
```

Comment: Um, [have you looked at the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)?

Comment: yes.  Although I'm assuming you meant to type a `$` instead of a `%` there

Comment: @Sam: Yes, I meant to type a `$`. I am still not used to PC keyboards (and PCs in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost - you should remove the `%`. Here's an example, which worked locally with PHP 5.3.4 :

```
$foo = array("1" => "First", "2" => "Second");

foreach($foo as $key => & $element) {
    $element = $element . " With More Text Attached!\n";
}

print_r($foo);
```

**results in**

```
Array ( 
   [1] => First With More Text Attached! 
   [2] => Second With More Text Attached! 
)
```